# CKAN 2-level user group

Tags: ckan

Based on CKAN's documentation, each dataset is owned by an organization. A user within that organization will create dataset that belongs to the organization.

What I'd like to have is for an organization to have "subgroups", whereby a user in a subgroup can manage their own datasets.

For example in a government usage, the organization is the different agencies, and the subgroups are the departments within each agency.

I'm looking for a direction/documentation on how this can be done.

Answer (score 2):

Some instances have implemented this using Organization hierarchy. There is backend support on CKAN core, but the frontend needs to be implemented in an extension.

See for instance:

https://github.com/datagovuk/ckanext-hierarchy

Don't worry about the compatibility note on the README, the relevant code is available on CKAN 2.2.